# Checking integer against array index not working

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making an android app where you tap a button to stop a looping counter when it is showing a particular number. I have an array (aNums) holding some int values and want the counter to stop when it is clicked when showing the first number in the array (in this case "2"). For some reason however it decides to stop on "1" when clicked. I'm not sure if my code is just wrong or if there's a timing issue and it's stopping right when it's about to change to the number "2". Here is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public int a = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    TextView textView2;
    Button Stop;
    public Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateText();
            a = ++a % 10;
            if (a < 10) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }
    };

    public int aNums[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        loop();
        Stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Stop);
        Stop.setOnClickListener(handler2);
    }

    View.OnClickListener handler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (a == aNums[0]) {
                Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    public void loop() {
        handler.post(myRunnable);
    }

    public void updateText() {
        textView2.setText("" + a);
    }

    public void Stop() {
        super.onStop();
        handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: yeah sure..`a == aNums[0]` invokes the `stop()` method

Answer (score 0):

You forgot two closing brackets here:

```
View.OnClickListener handler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i <= aNums.length; i++) {
                if (a == aNums[0]) {
                    Stop();
                } //I added this
            }
        }
}//and this
```

but I think there is no need for a for loop here: you want to stop the thread when you click at the moment `a` equals the number in your array at index 0, right?

```
View.OnClickListener handler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (a == aNums[0]) {
                Stop();
            }
        }
}
```

Also, this check is not necessary because `a` will never be 10 or more:

```
if (a < 10) {
     handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}
```

The last thing: when you quit the thread, the text is not updated. Try adding the `updateText()` after the click:

```
View.OnClickListener handler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (a == aNums[0]) {
                Stop();
                updateText();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks for catching that, I must've missed it. I took the for loop out but it still stops at "1" instead of "2" :(

Comment: Ok I put updateText in like you said but now it still doesn't stop on "2", instead if I click when it's on "1" the textview quickly changes to "2".

Comment: @HarryStanley I put the `updateText()` to the oncreate and after the assignment in the thread, take a look at http://www.codeshare.io/2z0vN

Comment: Ok now I've done that too and the problem persists. Do you think maybe there's a timing issue with the handler? Thanks for helping me out btw.

Comment: I'm not sure. I suggest debugging and checking the variables. (Going through the code step-by-step)